# IMPORTHTML - Google Sheets - Can't find specific table

Tags: google-sheets, importhtml

I'm trying to import a table on this page:

http://www.fangraphs.com/statsplits.aspx?playerid=13593&position=2B/SS&season=2017#advanced

As you can see there's three sections - "Standard", "Advanced" and "Batted Ball". I can't seem to get my IMPORTHTML function to find the "Advanced" table within the HTML. "0" returns the "Standard" table and I keep working my way up until nothing is returned.

I tried making sense of the source but I'm in over my head. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would help to show what you tried, because this should work:

```
=importhtml("http://www.fangraphs.com/statsplits.aspx?playerid=13593&position=2B/SS&season=2017","table",8)
```

Comment: I do not understand....... I tried this counting up from 0 to like 30 before I gave up. Not sure how I missed this. Thanks.